# Запятая между однородными придаточными с союзом "и"

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

В предложении

*Я чувствовал, что у меня уже губы искривились, подались куда-то в сторону* ***[,]***
*и мне никак не удаётся водворить их на место.*

запятой после "в сторону" по правилам, кажется, не должно быть. Насколько я понимаю, это придаточные с однородным подчинением и с союзом **и** (*я чувствовал что губы искривились и что мне не удается...*), которые не требуют запятой. В первом придаточном однородные сказуемые (*губы искривились, подались*) разделяются запятой, но второе сказуемое не требуется отделять запятыми с обеих сторон.

Однако у меня есть отчетливое чувство, что запятая здесь нужна. Так ли это на самом деле, и если так, то как правильно разобрать это предложение и какими правилами можно обосновать необходимость в этой запятой?

Comment: Мне кажется, ваши рассуждения верны и запятая не нужна. Однако я полагаю, что *подались куда-то в сторону* может (при желании автора) рассматриваться как уточняющий оборот: искривились, [а именно] подались куда-то в сторону... В таком случае запятая может стоять.

Comment: @Nektoid
Кстати, ваш вариант с пояснением "не прокатит" ни по семантике, ни по интонации. Семантические отношения между сказуемыми явно однородные, а произношение здесь с перечислением, с ударением на каждом сказуемом. Вообще говоря, зря вы не учитываете интонацию  (это же реальная запись живой речи), а вставочная интонация  никак не подойдет. Если уж хочется поставить запятую, то есть "дежурный" вариант  – считать союз И присоединительным. Это всегда нетрудно объяснить. Почему присоединительный? Семантика здесь разная, ситуации разные, я так вижу и т. д., а доказать обратное трудно.

Comment: @Nektoid И еще, каково ваше окончательное мнение: придаточные однородные или нет?

Comment: @Sharon у меня нет мнения.

Comment: Ну нет так нет.  Не очень приветливо, но очень понятно. Предлагаю закрыть форум на майские праздники.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***(1) Я чувствовал, что (2) у меня уже губы искривились, подались куда-то в сторону,** и (3) мне никак не удаётся водворить их на место.*

Желание автора поставить **запятую** вполне понятно – здесь ясно просматриваются **две разные ситуации.**

Казалось бы, это однородные придаточные 2 и 3, но их **структура** не соответствует такому пониманию.

В  предложении 2 мы должны обозначить перечисление **однородных сказуемых**, а потом присоединить к ним однородное придаточное 3. Тогда получается обозначение **трех однородных структур,** а это неверно. Поэтому мы не будем считать придаточные 2 и 3 однородными.

В этом случае союз И связывает СПП (предложения 1 и 2) и предложение (3).

Глагол ***чувствовал*** относится только к однородным сказуемым, а далее следует самостоятельное предложение, связанное по семантике с **волевым усилием.**

Сочинительная связь обозначается **запятой**.

Даже **интонационно** все это обозначено: сначала "слитно" читается фраза "губы искривИлись, подались куда-то в стОрону, потом делается пауза перед предложением (3).

Comment: *Я чувствовал, что... мне никак не удаётся водворить их на место* -- (3) тоже может относиться к "чувствовал". Более того, оно и должно относиться к "чувствовал", потому что, кроме как через ощущение, персонаж не может понять, удаётся ли ему водворить губы на место. Если он не перед зеркалом, конечно.

Comment: Позвольте с вами не согласиться. Если коротко: может относиться, но не обязано. Можно написать так: я чувствую, что губы искривились, съехали, но понимаю, что вернуть их на место. не могу. И дело здесь не в физиологии, а в том, как художник видит и описывает ситуацию, какие грамматические формы он для этого использует. Кстати, кроме семантики, здесь неоднородна и грамматика, а это уже намного важнее. Если не поставим запятую. то будем иметь три однородные структуры с замыкающим союзом И.

Comment: Хорошо, не обязано, но я считаю, что в ответе стоит отражать все варианты, даже маловероятные.

Comment: Я тоже сначала (всего-то полчаса назад) думала, что придаточные однородные.  Хотела написать, что  союз И можно считать при желании присоединительным.  Но  мне тут "подсказали" другое решение, и я с ним согласилась. Неоднородна именно грамматика (нет другого решения), а семантика – это лишь дополнительное пояснение.  Так что включайте интуицию, когда отвечаете на вопросы :)  Конечно, объяснение не самое простое - не все поймут.

Comment: Я предпочитаю включать мозг.

Comment: И как результаты, помогает? Мне кажется, что уж вам-то его, напротив,  нужно выключать для лучшего полета фантазии. :)

Comment: Полёт фантазии, он же поток сознания, противопоказан тем, кто не творит, собственно, в этом стиле. Сколь бы ни фантазировал архитектор, а здание, построенное поперёк законов физики или без арматурного каркаса, развалится. В литературе чуть по-иному, но примерно так же.

Comment: Возможно, вы правы, но я-то в школе мастерства не обучалась, аот и не знаю. Даа меня туда и не возьмут, слишком характер своевольный. А там, наверное, послушных любят...

Comment: Ну да, учиться-то ведь труднее, чем проявлять характер.